# BizTalk 2016 support “multisubnetfailover” if we connect staging database with WCF-Custom sql binding?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

We had issue during connection from BT to staging DB ( it has setup under AG listeners) and couldn’t able to enable RL and SP because by default WCF Custom sql bindings set “multisubnetfailover” to true.

Is there any work around to use AG listeners on Biztalk sql connection string without disable “multisubnetfailover” property to “False” ?

Comment: No. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1882a355-0abd-4e53-9bcb-a504ae96e687/understand-why-biztalk-does-not-support-multisubnetfailovertrue-in-availability-groups?forum=biztalkgeneral

Answer (score 0):

No.

[From High Availability using SQL Server Always On Availability Groups - BizTalk Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/high-availability-using-sql-server-always-on-availability-groups)

> **Support Availability Group Multi-Subnet Failovers**
> BizTalk Server uses Microsoft OLE DB for database connections, which does not support the MultiSubnetFailover connection option. BizTalk Server does not support the `MultiSubnetFailover (=TRUE)` connection option, and this may cause higher recovery time during multi-subnet failover.

Note: Although the above documentation has not been updated to state it, BizTalk 2020 may allow this for that adapters. See [MultiSubnetFailover connection option in BizTalk](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/biztalk-server-team-blog/multisubnetfailover-connection-option-in-biztalk/ba-p/1434903).